# android two alpha animations

Tags: android, animation

I'm trying to put in two alpha animations in one AnimationSet, as follows, but when I run it, the first (fadeout) animation happens, but it remains blank for the next animation. I understand that I can use a `repeatMode="reverse"` to do this, but I would like to know why this is not working in case I want to do something more fancy. Thanks.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
        <alpha
            android:duration="1000"
            android:fillAfter="false"
            android:fromAlpha="1.0"
            android:toAlpha="0.0" />
        <alpha
            android:duration="1000"
            android:fillBefore="false"
            android:fillEnabled="true"
            android:fromAlpha="0.0"
            android:startOffset="1000"
            android:toAlpha="1.0" />
    </set>
```

Comment: what does it do when you run it like this? You might try setting `fillAfter="true"` on the first one.

Comment: Is it Ok to have the same item twice in `<set>` tag?

Comment: @FoamyGuy: nothing happens...the view disappears for 2 seconds, then reappears.

Comment: @iturki: I'm not sure...good question though.

I just used two separate alpha animations, adding an animation listener to the first one to chain the two together.

Comment: @buntwoi Can you post the solution you used as an answer please. That will make it easier for people to find in the future when they are facing the same challenge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came to this post following the same thought.And i have tested this one now.
Unexpectedly its working perfect. Here goes my code.

```
    <alpha
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromAlpha="0.25"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:repeatMode="reverse"
        android:startOffset="500"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" />
    <alpha
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:repeatMode="reverse"
        android:startOffset="3500"
        android:toAlpha="0.25" />
```

The first one will set alpha to a higher value and its pulled low after some time using a second alpha. **Make sure you add "repeatMode" as "reverse"** , even though repeatcount is not set and no repeat happens. And the actual flow that happens is not reversing the first alpha , but switching to the second alpha for reverse operation .