# Android Alpha / Translate Animations

Tags: android, android-animation

I've got this animation which should move the applied view up out of the view whilst fading, move it back to below the view then back into the view whilst fading.

The problem is that it doesn't seem to fade - the opacity of the applied view is always `0.5`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:toYDelta="-200"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:duration="1995"
        android:startOffset="3000" />
    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="200"
        android:toYDelta="0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:duration="1995"
        android:startOffset="8005" />   

    <alpha
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:repeatMode="reverse"
        android:startOffset="3000"
        android:toAlpha="0.5" />
    <alpha
        android:duration="1995"
        android:fromAlpha="0.5"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:repeatMode="reverse"
        android:startOffset="8005"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" />
</set>
```

I've tried a number of things, nesting them in sets, removing the interpolator etc... The only thing that worked is using the example given in this SO question: [android two alpha animations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11894261/android-two-alpha-animations) which leads me to believe it's something to do with running the alpha animation when combined with the translate animation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you dont need to use two tranlate/alpha animations to get what you want, just use a  custom Interpolator

edit: see my answer from yesterday [Fade out animation works but opposite fade in animation does not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19205861/fade-out-animation-works-but-opposite-fade-in-animation-does-not/19206231#19206231)

Comment: That was something I copied from the SO question to get it to work (or not as the case may be). I'll give a custom interpolator a look.

Comment: see my modified answer

Comment: Adding the `fillEnabled` / `fillAfter` / `fillBefore` attribs in xml fixed the issue :)

Answer (score 7):

This is an example:

```
AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(true);
Animation trAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 500, 0, 0);
trAnimation.setDuration(6000);

trAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE); // This will make the view translate in the reverse direction

set.addAnimation(trAnimation);
Animation anim = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.0f);
anim.setDuration(3000);
set.addAnimation(anim); 

txtView.startAnimation(set); // replace this with your view
```

I hope this helps! You can change this and use the a layout based animation defining the alpha and translate animations under the set tag.

Comment: I should have mentioned I have also tried doing it in `C#` (it's MonoDroid) - exactly the same result happens.

Answer (score 3):

You Should try this:::

```
<alpha
    android:duration="200"
    android:fromAlpha="1.0"
    android:repeatCount="1"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:toAlpha="0.0" />

<translate
    android:duration="200"
    android:fromXDelta="0"
    android:repeatCount="1"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:toXDelta="50" />
```